# React native animated liquid fluid menu

Tags: react-native, fluid-layout, react-animated, liquid-layout

Effect that I would like to get, link: [Youtube](https://youtu.be/ZSw9C2wKVJE?t=2290), [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/8099130-The-Belgian-Waffles-App-Concept)

[image]

Effect I get:

[image]

The problem as seen from the image is the part of the selection on the left, that kind of white egg circle with the yellow circle inside it.

The effect that I would like to obtain is a liquid type effect, with the possibility that when passing from one menu to another the passage does not occur in a snap, but a passage that passes from one menu to another, as can be seen. in the video.

Any suggestions?

Link: [snack](https://snack.expo.io/BJhCPz2sS)

Code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

function Menu({ name, backgroundColor, color, select, onPress }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}
      activeOpacity={1}
      onPress={() => onPress(name)}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#2196f3',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          width: 80,
        }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#fff',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }],
          }}>
          {name}
        </Text>
        {select === name && (
          <View
            style={{
              width: 40,
              height: 60,
              borderRadius: 150 / 2,
              backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
              position: 'absolute',
              left: 60,
              alignItems: 'center',
              alignContent: 'center',
              alignSelf: 'center',
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                borderRadius: 20 / 2,
                backgroundColor: '#ffeb3b',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 5,
                top: 18,
                alignItems: 'center',
                alignContent: 'center',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                //marginTop: 30
              }}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

export default () => {
  const [select, setState] = useState('Classic');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{}}>
        <Menu name="Classic" select={select} onPress={name => setState(name)} />
        <Menu name="Music" select={select} onPress={name => setState(name)} />
        <Menu name="History" select={select} onPress={name => setState(name)} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```